# entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh" - docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint, docker-command

There is no such file by name `entrypoint.sh` in my workspace.

But below instruction in `docker-compose.yml` is referring it:

```
builder: 
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ../../target:/wheelhouse
  volumes_from:
    - cache
  entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh"
  command: ["pip", "wheel", "--non-index", "-f /build", "."]
```

---

where `../docker/dev/Dockerfile` has

```
# Set defaults for entrypoint and command string
ENTRYPOINT ["test.sh"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "test", "--noinput"]
```

---

What does `entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh"` actually do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh"` overrides `ENTRYPOINT ["test.sh"]` from Dockerfile.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint):

> Setting entrypoint both overrides any default entrypoint set on the
>   service’s image with the ENTRYPOINT Dockerfile instruction, and clears
>   out any default command on the image - meaning that if there’s a CMD
>   instruction in the Dockerfile, it is ignored.

- `ENTRYPOINT ["test.sh"]` is set in Dockerfile describing docker image
- `entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh"` is set in docker-compose file which describes multicontainer environment while referencing the Dockerfile.
- `docker-compose build builder` will build image and set entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["test.sh"]` set in Dockerfile.
- `docker-compose up builder` will start container  with entrypoint `entrypoint.sh pip wheel --no-index '-f /build' .` set in docker-compose file

Comment: The only thing make me wander is "There is no such file by name entrypoint.sh in my workspace." then how is overriding?

Comment: @Adiii there is `entrypoint.sh` in base docker image `FROM todobackendbase`. Base docker image copies `entrypoint.sh` in folder `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 4):

`ENTRYPOINT` is a command or script that is executed when you run the docker container.

If you specify `entrypoint` in the `docker-compose.yaml`, it overrides `ENTRYPOINT` from specified `Dockerfile`.

`CMD` is something that is passed as the parameters to the `ENTRYPOINT`

So if you just run the `dev/Dockerfile`, it would execute

`test.sh python manage.py test --noinput`

If you overrided `CMD` in `docker-compose.yaml` as you did, it would execute

`test.sh pip wheel --non-index -f /build .`

But because you also overrided `ENTRYPOINT` in your `docker-compose.yaml`, it is going to execute

`entrypoint.sh pip wheel --non-index -f /build .`

So basically, `entrypoint.sh` is a script that will run inside your container `builder` when you execute `docker-compose up` command.

Also you can check this answer for more info [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**
If the base image has `entrypoint.sh`, it will run that, but if you override with your own entrypoint then the container will run the override entrypoint.

If you to override the default behaviour of base image then you can change, ohterwise you do not need to override it from docker-compose.

**What does entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh" actually do?**

It totally depend on the script or command inside entrypoint.sh, but few things can be considered.

> ENTRYPOINT instruction allows you to configure a container that will
>   run as an executable. It looks similar to CMD, because it also allows
>   you to specify a command with parameters. The difference is ENTRYPOINT
>   command and parameters are not ignored when Docker container runs with
>   command line parameters. (There is a way to ignore ENTTRYPOINT, but it
>   is unlikely that you will do it.)

In simple word, entrypoint can be a complex bash script, for example in case of mysql [entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/3362baccb4352bcf0022014f67c1ec7e6808b8c5/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) which is more then 200 LOC which  does the following task.

- start MySQL server
- wait for MySQL server to up
- Create DB
- Can perform DB migration or DB initlization

So much complex task is not possible with CMD, as in CMD you can run the bash but it will be more headache to make it work. Also it make Dockerfile simple and put the complex task to entrypoint.

When there is entrypoint, anything that is passed to CMD will be consider as a argument for entrypoint.

In your case, CMD is `CMD ["python", "manage.py", "test", "--noinput"]` it will be passed as an argument and the best to run this is to use use

```
# set of command
#start long running process at the end that is passed from CMD
exec "$@"
```

> Finally, the exec shell construct is invoked, so that the final
>   command given becomes the container's PID 1. `$@` is a shell variable
>   that means "all the arguments",

[use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data](https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data)

[cmd-vs-entrypoint](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/)

Comment: Related to docker-compose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439706/volumes-from-instruction-docker-compose