# volumes_from instruction - docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

With the below `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
test:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes_from:
    - cachev

cachev:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - /build
  entrypoint: "true"
```

---

`cachev` service in above file launches volume container that creates  anonymous volume in `/var/lib/docker/` folder in docker host and creates mount point `/cache` within volume container(`xx_cachev`).

---

Does `volumes_from` instruction under `test` service create `/build` mount point in `xx_test` container? that points to `/build` mount point of `xx_cachev` container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `volumes_from` [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/):

> Mount all of the volumes from another service or container...

So the short answer is **yes**:

`volumes_from`  mounts `/build` volume defined  by `cachev` service inside `test` service.

Long answer:

To answer your question let's run the `test` service:

`docker compose up test`

Before answering your question, let's make sure the description is clear:

> cachev service in above file launches volume container...

It's just regular container which exits immediately because of `entrypoint: "true"`.

`docker ps -a` should show:

`ac68a33abe59       cache           "true"                   16 hours ago        Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                             cache_1`

But before it exits it creates volumes specified in `volumes:`. So we can call it volume container if its volumes are used by other service, for caching for instance.

> that creates anonymous volume in /var/lib/docker/ folder in docker host

Agree. `- /build` is anonymous volume. Can be verified by viewing all container mounts:

`docker inspect [cachev_container_id] --format '{{json .Mounts}}' | jq`

should show something like:

```
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "1ec7ff7c72bfb5a3259ed54be5b156ea694be6c8d932bcb3fa6e657cbcaea378",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/1ec7ff7c72bfb5a3259ed54be5b156ea694be6c8d932bcb3fa6e657cbcaea378/_data",
        "Destination": "/build",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
      }
```

`jq` is great utility for working with jsons in bash. Install it for the above command to work.

> and creates mount point /cache within volume container(xx_cachev).

Don't see any evidence of  mounts in `cachev:`  service spec you provided.

If you add mapping `- /tmp/cache:/cache` to its `volumes` section and run `docker compose up test` again and inspect the exited container you should see:

```
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/tmp/cache",
    "Destination": "/cache",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  }
```

Please, note that `docker inspect [cachev_service_id] --format '{{json .Mounts}}' | jq` will show all container mounts including those specified in `docker/dev/Dockerfile` using `VOLUME` instruction.

To **answer to your question** we need to inspect `test` service container:

`docker inspect [test_container_id] --format '{{json .Mounts}}' | jq`:

would show all the volumes specified in `docker/dev/Dockerfile` if any and all the volumes of `cachev` thanks to `volumes_from` instruction.

You can see that both `test` and `cache` containers have:

```
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "1ec7ff7c72bfb5a3259ed54be5b156ea694be6c8d932bcb3fa6e657cbcaea378",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/1ec7ff7c72bfb5a3259ed54be5b156ea694be6c8d932bcb3fa6e657cbcaea378/_data",
    "Destination": "/build",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
```

in their mounts and this volume survives subsequent runs of `docker compose up test`

Comment: So.. container goes in exited state after main process(process id 1) completes.. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, tests has finished. Containers stopped. You can rerun the stopped containers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can verify by executing a command inside both containers. if creat file in test container under `touch /build/fromtest.txt` path, it will be visible in cacheV container on the same path `/build/fromtest.txt`.

**volumes_from**

> Mount all of the volumes from another service or container

[compose-file-volumes_from](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/)

A demo you can try

```
test:
  image: alpine
  command: sh -c "touch /build/fromtest.txt && echo hell from test-container && ls /build/"
  volumes_from:
    - cachev

cachev:
  image: node:alpine
  command: sh -c "touch /build/fromcache.txt && echo hello from cache-container && ls /build/"
  volumes:
    - /build
```

log will be

```
Recreating compose-volume_cachev_1 ... done
Recreating compose-volume_test_1   ... done
Attaching to compose-volume_cachev_1, compose-volume_test_1
cachev_1  | hello from cache-container
test_1    | hell from test-container
test_1    | fromcache.txt
test_1    | fromtest.txt
cachev_1  | fromcache.txt
cachev_1  | fromtest.txt
```