# Best practice - Anonymous volume vs bind mount

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In a container,

anonymous volume can be created

with syntax(`VOLUME /build`) in `Dockerfile`

or

below syntax with `volumes` having `/build` entry

```
cache:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - /tmp/cache:/cache
    - /build
  entrypoint: "true"
```

---

My understanding is, both approach(above) make volume `/build` also available after container goes in `Exited` state.

Volume is anonymous because `/build` points to some random new location(in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` directory) in docker host

I see that anonymous volumes are more safer than named volumes(like `/tmp/cache:/cache`).

Because `/tmp/cache` location is vulnerable because there is more chance that this location is used by more than one docker container.

---

1)

Why anonymous volume usage is discouraged?

2)

Is

`VOLUME /build` in `Dockerfile`

not same as

```
volumes: 
 - /build
```

in `docker-compose.yml` file? Is there a scenario, where we need to mention both?

Comment: both anonymous and bind mounts can be reused by other containers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, anonymous volumes (`/build`) usage is [encouraged](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) over the use of [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) (`/tmp/cache:/cache`):

> Volumes have several advantages over bind mounts:
>
> - Volumes are easier to back up or migrate than bind mounts.
> - You can manage volumes using Docker CLI commands or the Docker API.
> - Volumes work on both Linux and Windows containers.
> - Volumes can be more safely shared among multiple containers.
> - Volume drivers let you store volumes on remote hosts or cloud providers, to encrypt the contents of volumes, or to add other
>     functionality.
> - New volumes can have their content pre-populated by a container.

Regarding your second question, yes. You can create anonymous volumes in docker-compose file or in the Dockerfile. No need to specify in both places.

Comment: Are you calling `/tmp/cache:/cache` a bind mount? Query edited..

Comment: Any idea on second question in the query?

Comment: you can create volumes using docker-compose without declaring them in the Dockerfile, so you can define anonymous volume just once

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a key third option, *named volumes*.  If you declare:

```yaml
version: '3'
volumes:
  build: {}
services:
  cache:
    image: ...
    volumes:
      - build:/build
```

Docker Compose will create a named volume for you; you can see it with `docker volume ls`, for example.  You can explicitly manage named volumes' lifetime, and set several additional options on them which are occasionally useful.  The Docker documentation has [a page describing named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) in some detail.

I'd suggest that named volumes are strictly superior to anonymous volumes, for being able to explicitly see when they are created and destroyed, and for being able to set additional options on them.  You can also mount the same named volume into several containers.  (In this sequence of questions you've been asking, I'd generally encourage you to use a named volume and mount it into several containers and replace `volumes_from:`.)

Named volumes vs. bind mounts have advantages and disadvantages in both directions.  Bind mounts are easy to back up and manage, and for content like log files that you need to examine directly it's much easier; on MacOS systems they are extremely slow.  Named volumes can run independently of any host-system directory layout and translate well to clustered environments like Kubernetes, but it's much harder to examine them or back them up.

You almost never need a `VOLUME` directive.  You can mount a volume or host directory into a container regardless of whether it's declared as a volume.  Its technical effect is to mount a new anonymous volume at that location if nothing else is mounted there; its practical effect is that it prevents future Dockerfile steps from modifying that directory.  If you have a `VOLUME` line you can almost always delete it without affecting anything.