# Correct path for rabbitmq Docker container in Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ Docker container in a docker-compose.yml file.

```
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61613:61613"
      - "15674:15674"
    volumes:
      - ./enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=default"
      - "traefik.ws.port=15674"
      - "traefik.ws.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/stomp/"
      - "traefik.web.port=15672"
      - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/rabbit/"
```

The problem is that when I do docker-compose up -d, there is an error.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Removing deploji-server_rabbit_1
deploji-server_postgres_1 is up-to-date
Starting 820ca92c591a_deploji-server_server_1 ...
Recreating 563cd247aa16_deploji-server_rabbit_1 ...
deploji-server_traefik_1 is up-to-date
Recreating 563cd247aa16_deploji-server_rabbit_1 ... error
Starting 98268bf1b8a7_deploji-server_worker_1   ... done

ERROR: for 563cd247aa16_deploji-server_rabbit_1  Cannot start service rabbit: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/Projects/deploji-server/enabled_plugins\\\" to rootfs \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bfcfb23713669e206d402b6c3a183d772750b527f35e5d0372d4f6982ddeb56aStarting 820ca92c591a_deploji-server_server_1   ... done
tmq/enabled_plugins\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for rabbit  Cannot start service rabbit: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/Projects/deploji-server/enabled_plugins\\\" to rootfs \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bfcfb23713669e206d402b6c3a183d772750b527f35e5d0372d4f6982ddeb56a/merged\\\" at \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bfcfb23713669e206d402b6c3a183d772750b527f35e5d0372d4f6982ddeb56a/merged/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

There seems to be no problems in Linux environment, only on Windows. I assume the path for enabled_plugins file is incorrect. I've tried changing the mapping to something like

- ./enabled_plugins:/c/rabbitmq

and the container seems to start, but the server is not responding, so I guess the plugins from the enabled_plugins file were not properly installed.

Whole docker-compose.yml file can be seen here: https://github.com/maxmeister/deploji-server/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Any advice on how could I make it run okay on my Windows machine? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes):
There are several options if use short syntax:

> SHORT SYNTAX Optionally specify a path on the host machine
>   (HOST:CONTAINER), or an access mode (HOST:CONTAINER:ro).
>
> You can mount a relative path on the host, that expands relative to
>   the directory of the Compose configuration file being used. Relative
>   paths should always begin with . or ...

```
volumes:
  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /var/lib/mysql

  # Specify an absolute path mapping
  - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql

  # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
  - ./cache:/tmp/cache

  # User-relative path
  - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro

  # Named volume
  - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463298/best-practice-anonymous-volume-vs-bind-mount/58463416#58463416) and answers

Comment: Thank you for answering. I guess the fourth option is to skip the mapping and then enter the container and manually enable a plugin through rabbitmq-plugins enable pluginname.